# name mangling with def file and extern "C"

Tags: com, visual-c++-2008

I'm creating a basic COM component so I can practice creating them.

I'm exporting DllRegisterServer, DllUnregisterServer,DllGetClassObject and DllCanUnloadNow from a .def file with the PRIVATE keyword(I think Microsoft requires it).

Anway, I specified all 4 functions with extern "C" and yet I'm still getting mangling.
Here is my .def:

```
EXPORTS
DllRegisterServer PRIVATE
DllUnregisterServer PRIVATE
DllGetClassObject PRIVATE
DllCanUnloadNow PRIVATE
```

Here is the mangling from dumpbin /EXPORTS

```
_DllCanUnloadNow@0
_DllGetClassObject@12
_DllRegisterServer@0
_DllUnregisterServer@0
```

I know the extern "C" helps, because I get really bad mangling without it, but I thought the .def with extern "C" was supposed to get rid of name mangling?

My compiler is VC++ Express 2008.
Linker Command Line:

/OUT:"G:\Programming\COM\BasicMathCOM\BasicMath\Release\BasicMath.dll" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /DLL /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"Release\BasicMath.dll.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"g:\Programming\COM\BasicMathCOM\BasicMath\Release\BasicMath.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /LTCG /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib

+/DEF:BasicMath.def, which I had added under additional options.

Comment: Is it possible that Visual Studio isn't using the def file?  Check the link command line for the /DEF option.

Comment: I saw it wasn't when dumpbin didn't give me any exports, so I added a /DEF and it gave me the mangled exports above.

Comment: Actually post the build log, not from the project options. <kbd>Ctrl</kdb> click it.

Comment: I tested it a trivial sample on both VC 2005 and 2008 and it works correctly, so it must be your end.

Comment: Somehow the Generate Debugging info got turned on. I'm not good at reading compiler command lines, so I didn't catch it until I saw a /DEBUG in a Release configuration and was stumped, so I searched around until I found the option and disabled it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I fixed it. When I was copying the command line into my question I saw a /DEBUG even though I had set the Release Configuration. I saw that the Generate Debugging Info had been inadvertently turned on, so I disabled it and re-compiled. The name mangling is gone.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually **using** the .def file?

Can we see your command line to compile?

Comment: I'll try and put it up. Before I wasn't getting any exports, so I went into my linker options and added a /DEF option.

Comment: Make sure you're building the configuration you think you are.